# Can two infinite loops be ran at once?

Tags: python, loops

I want to be able to have two `while True`loops running at the same time.
Would this be possible?

I am extremely new to Python, so I do not know how to get round this problem.

This is the code I made:

```
import time

def infiniteLoop():
    while True:
        print('Loop 1')
        time.sleep(1)

infiniteLoop()

while True:
    print('Loop 2')
    time.sleep(1)
```

Right now, it just prints a 'Loop 1'

Thanks in advance

Comment: You need two threads to run two loops.

Comment: Why do you want two separate loops running at the same time?

Comment: As you're using `time.sleep` instead of a more complex framework like twisted or tornado, you are tied to use threads.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To run both loops at once, you either need to use two threads or interleave the loops together.

Method 1:

```
import time
def infiniteloop():
    while True:
        print('Loop 1')
        time.sleep(1)
        print('Loop 2')
        time.sleep(1)

infiniteloop()
```

Method 2:

```
import threading
import time

def infiniteloop1():
    while True:
        print('Loop 1')
        time.sleep(1)

def infiniteloop2():
    while True:
        print('Loop 2')
        time.sleep(1)

thread1 = threading.Thread(target=infiniteloop1)
thread1.start()

thread2 = threading.Thread(target=infiniteloop2)
thread2.start()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Really helped!

Comment: it should be `target=infiniteloop1` instead of `target=infiniteloop1()` same with infiniteloop2

Answer (score 2):

While Brian's answer has you covered, Python's generator functions (and the magic of [`yield`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231767/what-does-the-yield-keyword-do-in-python)) allow for a solution with two actual loops and without threads:

```
def a():
    while True:  # infinite loop nr. 1 (kind of)
        print('Loop 1')
        yield

def b():
    for _ in a():    # infinite loop nr. 2
        print('Loop 2')

> b()
Loop 1
Loop 2
Loop 1
Loop 2
....
```

Here, the two loops in `a()` and `b()` are truly interleaved in the sense that in each iteration, execution is passed back and forth between the two.

Comment: Very similar to the first method I put ;)

Comment: Yes and no. Your first solution has only one loop at all (with two `print` statements).

Comment: func a() has direct impact on func b(), if func a() got stuck in some logic (may be network or db) then func b() code will not execute until func a() unblocks itself