# How to run two infinite loops at once python class

Tags: python, loops, class

So, i have example of code with two class functions with two infinite loops:

```
class Bot:
    def __init__(self):
        self.rocket = 0

    def func1(self):
        while True:
            self.rocket += 1

    def func2(self):
        while True:
            print(self.rocket)
```

I want them func1 and func2 to work at the same time. This is just an example, i dont need solution like:

```
class Bot:
    def __init__(self):
        self.rocket = 0

    def func1(self):
        while True:
            self.rocket += 1
            print(self.rocket)
```

Because i want a method how to run two functions with infinite loops in class ;) Thanks!I tried this, but causes errors:

```
from multiprocessing import Process

class Bot:
    def __init__(self):
        self.rocket = 0

    def func1(self):
        while True:
            self.rocket += 1

    def func2(self):
        while True:
            print(self.rocket)

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        p1 = Process(target=func1)
        p2 = Process(target=func2)
        p1.start()
        p2.start()
```

Comment: `causes errors` which are ?

Comment: This might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36847817/can-two-infinite-loops-be-ran-at-once/36848028

Comment: @azro _pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <function Bot.func1 at 0x03B02E88>: attribute lookup Bot.func1 on __main__ failed

Comment: @RoadRunner threading module is no longer available, idk about threading2

Comment: You have indentation error, starting at `if __name__ ....`. As it stands it want not work as you can't reach `p1.self.rocket` in process `p2`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You need a `Bot` instance to call `func1` and `func2` on
2. Use `threading.Thread` and not `multiprocessing.Process`, to get details read [What are the differences between the threading and multiprocessing modules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18114285/what-are-the-differences-between-the-threading-and-multiprocessing-modules#answers)
   , the point to get for here is

   > Threads share data by default; processes do not.

Using `Process` you'll see only `0` printing, the `func1` process will has its own data and update `rocket` for him only and `func2` Process won't be able to acess it, using `Thread` they will share the data

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    from threading import Thread

    b = Bot()
    p1 = Thread(target=b.func1)
    p2 = Thread(target=b.func2)
    p1.start()
    p2.start()
```

Comment: THANKS A LOT! Rly azro you're the best, saved my life. Do everything you want, you are genius, really appreciated

Comment: @RArtur you're exagerating, but thanks